# Best way to get distinct rows from a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables tbPerson and tbComment with data such as below:

```
tbPerson
PersonID FirstName LastName
1        William   Tell
2        Joe       Smith
3        Sam       Hampton

tbComment
CommentID    PersonID   CommentValue               CommentPosition
45           2          This is my comment         100
46           2          This is my second comment  100
47           2          This is my third comment   100
48           1          A comment                  101
49           3          This comment rules         102
50           3          A comment here             102
```

I need a query that only returns:

```
William Tell 101
Joe Smith    100
Sam Hampton  102
```

I figured it was something like below but this returns multiple rows. I only want the three rows.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, CommentPosition
FROM tbPerson
JOIN tbComment ON tbPerson.PersonID = tbComment.PersonID
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, CommentPosition
```

Answer (score 1):

For your data, your query should return only three rows.  If you have multiple comments for a person, You need to choose which comment position you want.

The following would return the minimal value:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, MIN(CommentPosition) as CommentPosition
FROM tbPerson JOIN
     tbComment
     ON tbPerson.PersonID = tbComment.PersonID
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName;
```

Notice that `CommentPosition` was removed from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If comment position varies, try this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, CommentPosition
FROM tbPerson
INNER JOIN (
SELECT PersonID, MIN(CommentPosition) AS CommentPosition
FROM tbComment
GROUP BY PersonID
) T1 ON tbPerson.PersonID = T1.PersonID
```

This will also handle the case of multiple people with the same name.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, ...`to get exactly what you want. Here's a tutorial on it.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx